# What's the word for when someone tries to one up them about being in a worse position?

Tags: single-word-requests

Like the inverse of one-upmanship. For example, if you mention that you're a little short on money this month and then a certain type of friend begins to discuss how they are the single poorest person to ever walk the earth as if to prove they are much more efficient at being living in poverty.

It might just be "one-upmanship" but I'm curious to know if there's a word for when a said person seemingly wants to appear worse off or in a worse position than someone else.

Comment: For ailments, [one-upmanship syndrome](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/one-upmanship+syndrome)  "...the habit of some patients of exaggerating the symptoms of their particular condition—e.g., worse symptoms, greater pain, ...  which may evoke greater sympathy in spectators."

Comment: Well, since the 60s, and the Monty Python 'Four Yorkshireman' sketch I've always called such people *professional Yorkshiremen*, though I realise I probably shouldn't.  *Well when I say 'house' it was only a hole in the ground covered by a piece of tarpolin, but it was a house to US* and so forth

Comment: You could of course coin "one-downmanship." But maybe this is a duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287760/describe-a-person-who-brags-about-difficulties

Comment: Isn't a race to the bottom still one-upmanship?

Comment: "Andy Bonner 'One-downmanship' is probably transparent, but non-standard and thus needing careful handling.

Comment: @High Performance Mark:None of us was ever anything like a *Professional* Yorkshireman.  We couldn't afford the uniform or the equipment, but we made do with what we had.

Comment: Perhaps a variation of the [pity/sympathy ploy](https://narcissistabusesupport.com/red-flags/red-flags-narcissist-guilt-trips-pity-ploys-obligation/)?

Comment: Some thoughts : If "**more efficient** at being living in poverty" is the key, then "humble-bragging" may be used. If we are making new words, then I suggest "woe-champion" or "woe-king" or "woe-queen" or "misery-master" ....

Comment: @Elliot , Lucky you !! You could make do with what you had !! I had literally nothing to make do with .... I could not even Dream to be a Part-time Wannabe Amateur Yorkshireman ....

Comment: @Prem; (lol out loud) Of course we didn't have much to work with at that. A scrap of greasy cardboard and a broken stick. But that was our uniform and we turned out right enough.